# MySql - get related rows with a specific condition, or get null if there isn't any row that matches the condition

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using MySql 8.0.16-7.

Tables are as shown:

```
product:
| product_no | product_name | 
| 1          | p1           | 
| 2          | p2           | 
| 3          | p3           |

product_puser: (product - M:N - puser)
| product_no | puser_no |
| 1          | 1        |
| 1          | 2        |
| 2          | 3        |
| 2          | 4        |

puser:
| puser_no | puser_type | puser_name | 
| 1        | 10         | u1         | 
| 2        | 20         | u2         | 
| 3        | 20         | u3         | 
| 4        | 30         | u4         |
```

Now, I want to list ALL products. I also want to get the information of related users whose 'puser_type' is 10, if exists:

```
What I want:

| product_no | product_name | puser_no | puser_name | 
| 1          | p1           | 1        | u1         | 
| 2          | p2           | (null)   | (null)     | <- p2 has some users, but none of them are type 10.
| 3          | p3           | (null)   | (null)     | <- p3 has no user
```

I had to use LEFT JOIN (not INNER JOIN) to include p2 and p3 in the result. The problem is, there are several duplicated rows as many times as there are product_puser rows:

```
SELECT product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_name FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_puser AS pu ON pu.product_no = product.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser AS u ON u.puser_no = pu.puser_no AND u.puser_type = 10;

| 1 | p1 | 1      | u1     | 
| 1 | p1 | (null) | (null) | 
| 2 | p2 | (null) | (null) | 
| 2 | p2 | (null) | (null) | 
| 3 | p3 | (null) | (null) |
```

I tried to apply GROUP BY, but there was still a row that I do not want:

```
SELECT product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_name FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_puser AS pu ON pu.product_no = product.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser AS u ON u.puser_no = pu.puser_no AND u.puser_type = 10
-- (@@SQL_MODE contains 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', so I need to specify all columns in GROUP BY clause.)
GROUP BY product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_name;

| 1 | p1 | 1      | u1     | 
| 1 | p1 | (null) | (null) |  <- This row
| 2 | p2 | (null) | (null) | 
| 3 | p3 | (null) | (null) |
```

Is there any way to solve this? If possible, I want to use only pure(?) SQL, without any use of MySQL specific function, etc.

.........

After I'd written this question above, I thought of another idea, JOINing tables twice and counting:

```
test:

SELECT product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_type, u.puser_name, COUNT(u2.puser_no) FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_puser pu ON pu.product_no = product.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser AS u ON u.puser_no = pu.puser_no AND u.puser_type = 10
LEFT JOIN product_puser AS pu2 ON pu2.product_no = product.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser AS u2 ON u2.puser_no = pu2.puser_no AND u2.puser_type = 10
GROUP BY product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_type, u.puser_name

                       count(users of type 10)
| 1 | p1 | - | -  | -  | 1 | 
| 1 | p1 | 1 | 10 | u1 | 1 | 
| 2 | p2 | - | -  | -  | 0 | 
| 3 | p3 | - | -  | -  | 0 | 

add HAVING:

SELECT product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_type, u.puser_name, COUNT(u2.puser_no) FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_puser pu ON pu.product_no = product.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser AS u ON u.puser_no = pu.puser_no AND u.puser_type = 10
LEFT JOIN product_puser AS pu2 ON pu2.product_no = product.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser AS u2 ON u2.puser_no = pu2.puser_no AND u2.puser_type = 10
GROUP BY product.product_no, product.product_name, u.puser_no, u.puser_type, u.puser_name
HAVING (u.puser_type = 10 OR COUNT(u2.puser_no) = 0)

| 1 | p1 | 1 | 10 | u1 | 1 | 
| 2 | p2 | - | -  | -  | 0 | 
| 3 | p3 | - | -  | -  | 0 |
```

**Now I've got what I want. But I still can not be sure this is the right and best approach. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.**

Here is the SQL script that I used to test, for your convenience:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_puser;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS puser;

CREATE TABLE product (
    product_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(255)
    );

INSERT INTO product VALUES (1, 'p1'), (2, 'p2'), (3, 'p3');

CREATE TABLE product_puser (
    product_no INTEGER,
    puser_no INTEGER
    );

INSERT INTO product_puser VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4)
;

CREATE TABLE puser (
    puser_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    puser_type INTEGER,
    puser_name VARCHAR(255)
    );

INSERT INTO puser VALUES
(1, 10, 'u1'),
(2, 20, 'u2'),
(3, 20, 'u3'),
(4, 30, 'u4')
;
```

Comment: Except for the desired result, I reckon you can delete from this question everything before the `........`

Comment: What if there are 2 separate user relater to some product with `puser_type = 10`?

Comment: @Strawberry I understand what you said. English is not my mother language and I feel difficult to describe my previous tries and current situation each time when someone asks me in comments. So I'd tried to describe them in full detail as possible. Is it ok if I edit my post to adjust order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it safe for you?

```
SELECT p.product_no, 
       p.product_name, 
       MAX(u.puser_no) puser_no, 
       MAX(u.puser_name) puser_name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_puser pu 
    ON p.product_no = pu.product_no
LEFT JOIN puser u 
    ON pu.puser_no  = u.puser_no 
    AND u.puser_type  = 10
GROUP BY p.product_no, 
         p.product_name;
```

Comment: Thank you. If it is the case that there can be at most only one user with type-10 for each product, I could use this. However, currently I can not assume that.

Comment: @gypark *If it is the case that there can be at most only one user with type-10 for each product* imagine that there is more than 1 such user... how does the output must look like in this case? for example, you may show all users in one column as CSV list... in such case simply replace `MAX()` with `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. I found the code from your answer has a problem that `MAX(u.puser_no)` and `MAX(u.puser_name)` might be from different users if there are more than one user with type-10. For example, if there are (1, 10, 'u1) and (5, 10, 'u0'), this query print (5, 'u1') as puser. `GROUP_CONCAT` can be a good solution and I'll check if I can use it for my real application. Thank you.

Comment: @gypark *I found the code from your answer has a problem that MAX(u.puser_no) and MAX(u.puser_name) might be from different users* That is a norma - these two MAX selections are independent. If you need one record then you need additional subquery which will select one `puser_no` per `product_no` from all matched and restrict the output according this value. In such code neither GROUP BY nor MAX() are needed.